# Google sheets API in PHP

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-sheets-api

I have a privately owned spreadsheet with automatic data updated by formula, frequently. With Google sheets API, the live data from sheet cannot be fetched. I have a cron job at every 30mins once to fetch the spreadsheet data to my mysql DB. But while checking mysql table records the data are same. since the cell values often got updated, the table records shows variations, but not. I have used the below code.
How do i get the latest data inserted my db via my cron job. Great Thanks..

i have tried the below code.

```
 `require '../vendor/autoload.php';
  putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=myserviceaccount.json');
  use Google\Client;
  use Google\Service\Drive;
  use Google\Service\Sheets;
  $client = new \Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName('Apllication Name');
  $client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets');
  $client->setAccessType('offline');
  $path = 'credentials.json';
  $client->setAuthConfig($path);
  $tokenPath = 'token.json';
  if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
       $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
       $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
  }`

`if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
    $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
} else {
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
    print 'Enter verification code: ';
    $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

    $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
    $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
        throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
    }
}
if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
    mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
}
file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
```

}

```
$client->setHttpClient(new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['headers' => ['Cache-Control' => 'no-cache']]));
$service = new \Google_Service_Sheets($client);

sleep(10);//here added some delay since my sheet values got updated by formula
$spreadsheetId = 'myspreadsheetid';
$spreadsheet = $service->spreadsheets->get($spreadsheetId);
var_dump($spreadsheet);
$range = 'Sheet1!A2:Z6'; 
 $response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
if ($response instanceof \Google_Service_Exception) {
$client->revokeToken();
$client->getAccessToken(true);
$response = $sheetsService->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
 }
$values = $response->getValues();
var_dump($values);`
```

Comment: What does `sheet cannot be fetched` mean? Is there an error?

Comment: *"spreadsheet with automatic data updated by formula"* What does it mean?

Comment: @JohnHanley the values in the spread sheet have been fetched but the values are not the latest values from sheet. it always shows the old values of cells. The cell values are often changed by formula.

Comment: @Olivier my spread sheet cell values are frequently changed by formula. But it has not been got by google sheet api request. when I run the script, the api results the old values of cells